# Avoiding PHP render "<?" as a self opening tag

Tags: php

In a php file I have the following

```
<script id="svg-xml" type="text/template">
    <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <etc />
</script>
```

and **`<?`** in the beginning of XML declaration is rendered as the short form of the PHP opening tag. My solution is to make PHP echo the `<` sign and use it like `<?='<'?>?xml version=...`. Is there any other/better option out there that is more elegant?

**[EDIT]** I'm looking for an alternative PHP approach, if any. Also, I'm not planning to turn short tags off since I'm using many of them here and there in this page.

Comment: Why do you want this ?

Comment: @MoeedFarooqui Because I'm using this!

Comment: Maybe it would be a good idea to start using a [template engine](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Echo the whole line, which is more readable than you proposition.

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>';?>
```

You could also disable short tags in your configuration. (Obviously this is not a solution if you rely elsewhere on short tags.

Comment: You're right, I don't want to disable short tags, and yes, your solution definitely seems more readable. But I was wondering if there's another approach than to make it echo certain part of that string.

Comment: +1 .. If you're considering PHP to be parsed as XML this is the best option.

Answer (score 1):

Simply disable [short open tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use) with the [`short_open_tag` directive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag). The precise mechanism depends on how you run PHP.

---

Right, I've just seen your edit about not wanting to use this. Then, this question is becoming subjective since it depends on your idea of what *more elegant* means.

If using a variable/constant is more elegant:

```
<?php

define('XML_INIT', '<?xml');

?>
<script id="svg-xml" type="text/template">
    <?=XML_INIT?> version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <etc />
</script>
```

If using an external file is more elegant:

```
<script id="svg-xml" type="text/template">
<?php readfile('./template.svg'); ?>
</script>
```

If using heredoc is more elegant:

```
<script id="svg-xml" type="text/template">
<?php echo <<<EOM
    <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <etc />
EOM
?>
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You seem to be focusing on making your PHP code as readable as possible.
take a look at [XHP](https://github.com/facebook/xhp), which is used internally at Facebook to make PHP more readable.

Here are a few example of valid XHP code (which is an extension of PHP so you can do anything you do in PHP there):

```
<?php
$href = 'http://www.facebook.com';
echo <a href={$href}>Facebook</a>;
```

Second line is not a string, but something you can echo directly in XHP.
I don't see much point in copy paste doc samples from the site, if you find it interesting go ahead and give it a try.
it takes time to get used to, but the result is much cleaner PHP code that is also more secure and less bug-prone.

Comment: First, whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Second, tthe answer is incorrect. The asker is not looking for a library to replace HTML. He only wants to output that single tag.

Comment: You may be color blind, but the XHP text is indeed a link to the library.
the author is trying to make his PHP look more readable, which is what this library is all about.

Comment: he isn't looking for a library to replace HTML. He's looking for a place to readably embed _one tag_ into a PHP page. Ad-hominem attacks won't change the fact, nor will they change the fact that this is a link-only answer. Note that technically, color blindness does not prevent one from distinguishing hyperlinks from the usual text. Note that I never disputed that you were linking to a library,  only that the library was useful to the asker.

Comment: @OmryYadan - Yes, it's obvious that your question is a link to a tool. That's the problem: there's no way to know what your answer is about until you follow the link. And even after having a quick look it isn't entirely clear how that applies to this specific problem. Stack Overflow wouldn't be as useful as it is if it was a mere link directory.